# How to select a specific Postgres schema with reactive datasource in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, reactive-postgresql-client

Today with the below configuration it is connecting to the default schema of a db , how to configure to connect to a specific schema.
[image]

references :

```
https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#postgresql-2

Any leads will be really helpful.
```

Comment: I'm connecting to a specific schema, but without reactive datasource. I use like this `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=broker`. Besides this, I inform `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql`, `quarkus.datasource.username=postgres` and `quarkus.datasource.password=postgres`. Does it makes any sense for your question? The key idea is to inform `?currentSchema=broker` on the end of the JDBC url.

Comment: @FelipeWindmoller

I am using quarkus-reactive-pg-client to connect to postgres db , and below is how the configuration needs to be supplied.  
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username = ${DB_USERNAME:postgres}
quarkus.datasource.password = ${DB_PASSWORD:postgres}
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url = ${DB_URL:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb}

Comment: But I am not able to find the configuration to add the schema

Comment: Here is the reference link :
https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#postgresql-2

Comment: @Felipe Windmoller I want to work with reactive datasource , native jdbc I am aware .

Comment: is it possible to add `?currentSchema=YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME` to the end of your JDBC URL? Like `quarkus.datasource.reactive.url = ${DB_URL:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb?currentSchema=YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME}`

Comment: `postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb?currentSchema=user1` , the application is starting without error , however when I send the query it is not fetching the data from the schema user1 , it is fetching data from the default schema .

Comment: sorry to hear that. For me this worked. When I inform `?currentSchema=YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME` on my JDBC URL, I execute my SQLs without informing the schema name and it works. If you can fix your problem, please post here. I don't know if this would help, but [this project](https://github.com/felipewind/fix-trading-simulator/tree/main/broker-back-end) uses conventional database (not reactive) with a specific schema. Good luck!

Comment: The Vert.xSQL client [doesn't seem to have that configuration at the moment](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/#_connection_uri). You can try to open an issue on [the GitHub project](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding **search_path** to the connection uri will fetch results from specific schema.

Below configuration worked.

> postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb?search_path=user1

Below is the class that parse the db configuration

io.vertx.pgclient.impl.PgConnectionUriParser

Thank You David for the leads.

Reference : https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/#_connection_uri

Comment: Ah ah ... I read the list of supported properties in the URI twice and missed it :) That's why I didn't expect it to work. Nice that it's there

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: you can actually use `search_path` as [connection uri property](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/#_connection_uri).

I haven't tested it, but I would try this:

```
quarkus.datasource.reactive.additional-properties=search_path=user1
```

`search_path` is the property used by Postgres to [define the schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html). The syntax of the configuration is how [Smallrye Config](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/2.11.0/config/map-support/) reads parameters as map.

Comment: Tried this , the application is running but the query returns no data

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to quarkus 3.1.0

```
quarkus.datasource.reactive.additional-properties.search_path=my_schema
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).